# FreeType 2 character exact size and exact position

Tags: c++, freetype

Making some experiments with ttf fonts, and tried to use famous font rendering library FreeType, version 2.5.3.

My code:

```cpp
#include "ft2build.h"
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

#define FONTPATH "<font path here>"
const char* fontfile=FONTPATH "<fontname here>.TTF";
const int w=25;
const int h=25;
char* outbitmap;

int main() {
    outbitmap=new char[w*h];
    memset(outbitmap,0,w*h);
    FT_Library ftl;
    FT_Error err=FT_Init_FreeType(&ftl);
    FT_Face fface;
    err=FT_New_Face(ftl,fontfile,0,&fface);
    err=FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(fface,w,h);
    FT_UInt ch;
    //ch=0x3042; //あ
    //ch='_';
    ch='|';
    FT_UInt chridx=FT_Get_Char_Index(fface,ch);
    err=FT_Load_Glyph(fface,chridx,FT_LOAD_DEFAULT);
    err=FT_Render_Glyph(fface->glyph,FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);
    for(int y=0;y<fface->glyph->bitmap.rows;++y) {
        int outy=fface->glyph->bitmap.rows-fface->glyph->bitmap_top+y; //???how to get baseline position
        for(int x=0;x<fface->glyph->bitmap.width;++x) {
            int outx=fface->glyph->bitmap_left+x;
            outbitmap[outy*w+outx]=fface->glyph->bitmap.buffer[fface->glyph->bitmap.width*y+x];
        }
    }
    delete[] outbitmap;
    err=FT_Done_Face(fface);
    err=FT_Done_FreeType(ftl);
    return 0;
}
```

So I have some questions.
Assume that I need render one character to byte array with fixed size, in correct position.
Character size must be exactly size that fits in output bitmap, no clipping allowed.
It's OK to ignore kerning completely.

1. I specified character width=height=25. But for '|' it gives fface->glyph->bitmap.rows==26.
   How should I set height to get exactly 25px output, not 26, for any normal font? If it isn't 
   possible, then is there any way to calculate output character height exactly in pixels before 
   FT_Render_Glyph. FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes doesn't work well enough, so I getting +1px sometimes.
2. How do I get baseline position for any given font? If I have baseline, I can place character
   in exactly right position. I have no 1000x1000 screen, just one bitmap 25x25.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is super late but I just found out how to do this:

1. (Getting the character height in pixels). From what I understand setting the font size (e.g. with `FT_Set_Char_Size`) really just defines a scaling between font units and pixel units ([this explains more](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-2.html#section-2)). I.e., 12pt font at 72dpi does not necessarily mean the glyph is 12 pixels high. You can, however, get a bounding box that I am pretty sure will enclose every single glyph in the chosen font. This is how I did it:

```
    //12pt font
    double font_size = 12.0;   

    //Resolution means DPI here
    double pixel_size = font_size * resolution / 72; 

    //Font height and width in pixels
    int font_height = round((face->bbox.yMax - face->bbox.yMin)*pixel_size / face->units_per_EM);
    int font_width = round((face->bbox.xMax - face->bbox.xMin)*pixel_size / face->units_per_EM);
```

2. This is how I got a baseline height. It's just the maximum descent below the baseline of any glyph. When paired with the above code, drawing your glyph with the baseline at this position should guarantee that all glyphs will fit in the bounding box.

```
    //Convert this to pixel_size if your DPI is not 72
    double font_size = 12.0;

    //Height in pixels (using a double for sub-pixel precision)
    double baseline_height = abs(face->descender) * font_size / face->units_per_EM;
```

(Where `face` is the font you have loaded).

EDIT: forgot to account for DPI, in my application I was just using 72 so it canceled out

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered anything, so posting some more workarounds than answers I found by myself.

For question 1, I can probably live with that after applying following:

```
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(fface,w-1,h-1);
```

or maybe even

```
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(fface,w-w%2,h-h%2);
```

For question 2 I don't know yet ...

Comment: except I wanted to characters be 25 px width, but they become 24px after workaroud above.

Comment: you should use FT_Request_Size instead